# PHP, error when curl_exec($ch) in Jira-> Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, curl, jira

I got a null object when i execute this code, i dont find what its wrong.

```
 $data = array(
"fields" => array(
    "project" => array(
        "key" => "ISSGS"
    ),
    "summary" => "Try",
    "description" => "Try2",
    "assignee"=>array("name"=>"myName"),
    "issuetype" => array(
        "name" => "Proyect"
    ),
    "customfield_10490"=>array("value"=>"INEKN")
)
```

);

```
function post_to($data) {

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/JSON');

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => URL_JIRA,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ':' . $password,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jdata,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
return json_encode($result);
}

$result = post_to($data);

if (property_exists($result, 'errors')) {
    echo "Error(s) creating issue:\n";
 }else {
    echo "New issue created at " . URL_JIRA . "{$result->key}\n";
 }
```

Is not an URL or username/pass problem, the problem is the function post_to() is returning NULL.

Comment: check what you are getting in `$result` post output on `curl_exec`

Comment: In the function `post_to` where is `$jdata` defined? you pass `$data` into `post_to` but never use it. Is `$jdata` a typo?